# errors occurring while converting mysqli into PDO

Tags: php, pdo, hhvm

i am converting mysqli into PDO and then running my application in hiphop(hhvm), getting the following errors..please help me !!!

HipHop Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$sessionTimeOut in /var/www/webApp/services/adminSessionSettingService.php on line 204

HipHop Warning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/webApp/config.php on line 116

HipHop Warning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/webApp/userLoginController.php on line 52

HipHop Warning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/webApp/userLoginController.php on line 61

HipHop Warning: Cannot access property on non-object in /var/www/webApp/userLoginController.php on line 61

Comment: This is extremely googleable error message.

Answer (score 0):

Rule of the thumb:

## Never "convert" your application.

but write it from scratch, as though there was no previous version at all.

If it asked for the conversion - then it was poorly written. And just a plain "conversion" will do no good for it. Learn better practices (such as DBAL, Query builder, ORM) and then rewrite your application using them, instead of just mechanical transition from one API to another.